# How can i get whole shop list in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to check each store's average score.

my ‘shop’ table is
[image]

my ‘order’ table is
[image]

My SQL is :

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,AVG(b.point) as point
from shop a
LEFT JOIN order b on a.id=b.shop_id
WHERE b.point<>0
GROUP BY(b.shop_id)
```

but this SQL only can check out the shop had point in ‘order’ table.

How can i get whole shop list in SQL?

Comment: Provide data please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.NAME,
    AVG(b.point) AS point
FROM
    shop a
LEFT JOIN `ORDER` b ON a.id = b.shop_id AND b.point <> 0
GROUP BY a.id
```

Since `b.shop_id` can be `NULL` so that you need to group by `a.id` in order to get result for all shop ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,It is the perfect answer to my question